# Add new instance of a class to the Vector

Tags: java, vector

There is the following data structure:

```
Vector<Cluster> clustersList;
```

During the iterative process I add new elements to `clustersList`.

```
Cluster c1 = getCluster();
clustersList.add(c1);
```

The problem is that at the last iteration the first element (`((0)(2))`) is substituted by the last one (`(((0)(2))((1)(6)))`), ie:

```
[((0)(2))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6)), ((3)(7))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6)), ((3)(7)), ((5)(8))]
[(((0)(2))((1)(6))), ((1)(6)), ((3)(7)), ((5)(8)), (((0)(2))((1)(6)))]
```

The result must be:

```
[((0)(2))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6)), ((3)(7))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6)), ((3)(7)), ((5)(8))]
[((0)(2)), ((1)(6)), ((3)(7)), ((5)(8)), (((0)(2))((1)(6)))]
```

How can I get such result?

P.S. I don't use any ID inside the class Cluster.

Comment: The Vector only hold reference to Cluster objects, it doesn't hold the actual object. So if somewhere else the object is modified, you can end up with that situation

Comment: @gerrytan: So, is it better to use ArrayList in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first cluster is some object (from `new Cluster()`) whose content is overwritten by the value of the last element.

You would not have this conceptual problem, if the class were immutable like String. The solution (for now) would be to add at some place(s) a `new Cluster()`.

P.S.

Use `List<Cluster> clusterList = new ArrayList<>();` - the newer classes, a bit faster.